# html and javascript - make radio buttons visible after scrolling

Tags: javascript, html

I am just wondering if anyone out there knows if it is possible to only make radio buttons visible once a user scrolls to the bottom of text area with javascript (licence agreement).

I would like to have a scrollable text area with two radio buttons (agree and decline) underneath that cannot be selected till the text area has been read and the bottom of it has been reached.

If this is possible could you give an example of the code needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to have a div with a `height` and `overflow` css properties defined and put the radio boxes at the bottom so the use will have to scroll the area to see the radio buttons.

You have the following HTML:

```
<div id="license">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" value="Y" /><label>Agree</label>
        <input type="radio" value="N" /><label>Disagree</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The according CSS to achieve what you're after:

```
#license {
    height: 200px; 
    overflow-y: scroll;  // show vertical scrollbar
    overflow-x: hidden;  // hide horizontal scrollbar
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/ntnFD/)**